# How to set the rule for C# coding without use of Style Cop,Code Anylysis rule set,FxCop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, coding-style

We want globally to define  C# coding style rule such as the variable declaration rule, method definition rule etc.For this we are looking for the Visual studio 2015 extension or in any in build function.For Some reason we dont want to use Style Cop,Code Analysis Rule Set,FxCop.Is there any other way to do this?